# Do timed pointers exist?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

In some cases I desired to have some kind of timed-based smart pointer, for example to cache some bulky object but release it automatically after a certain time if not used. When the pointer is touched (dereferenced) the count down is restarted, and you can also halt the count down if you need to 'lock' the object alive for duration of a computation. Something like:

```
timed_ptr<Type,30> p = new Type(); \\object is deleted after 30 seconds, and pointer set to a checkable 'null' state

...

p.stop_count_down();
// do something with the object, guaranteed it won't expire while we still need it. 
p.start_count_down();
```

Does anything of this sort exists in boost or other library?

Comment: It seems like having such a high-level concept (temporal resource allocation) tied to such a low-level one (smart object references) would lead to very brittle and inherently non-deterministic programs.

Comment: It should not be hard to implement this, right?

Comment: @MooseBoys Possibly. It might be an animal to be handled carefully, but I would like to have one and play around with it.

Comment: @Zereges no, combine shared_ptr and weak_ptr maybe.

Comment: Would be useful when implementing cache?

Comment: Perhaps what you want instead of this is an LRU cache?  (I think there is probably nothing special about 30 seconds or any other timeout-period you might use; rather you want to free up the least-likely-to-be-needed-in-the-near-future expendable resources whenever 'too many' resources are in use at once, for some value of 'too many')

Comment: @MooseBoys That aspect can easily be solved. You jut have some protocol for picking up the pointer into use, and dropping it again. The pointer only expires in the quiescent period when it's not in use. The operation for bringing a pointer into use is made atomic so that if you successfully get a reference, it is safe from expiry.  In the above example, the `stop_count_down` operation would have to return a value indicating success or failure: is the pointer still good, or was it too late to stop the countdown.

Comment: Timed smart pointers sound like a debugging nightmare.

Comment: @PerryC not if there is some simple way to disable them, if it is a problem. Like don't launch the global thread which performs the expiry of all these pointers.    The expiry could also be synchronous: as in, the app has to call something to trigger expiry.

Comment: Sounds like caching. There should be several caching-schemes out there. A timed one, maybe. Anyway you might put that pointer into a cache and do not leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are losing the benefit of a smart pointer by timing it. Just have some object responsible for managing these resources and request the resource from it when needed. Otherwise, you will need to put checks if the resource is still loaded before any use of the pointer. This is the exact problem of shared pointers where some other code might invalidate the resource/memory, and you must always validate the pointer's resource before using it.

Comment: Yes, there is some analogy with weak_ptr. But my question is not about discussing possible benefits/shortcomings, it's about whether this kind of object exists somewhere.